# I want to leave conditions in the search form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to leave search criteria when searched

And I wrote

**project.index**

```
<form action="{{ route('project.post.index') }}" method="post">
@csrf
<input type="search" name="project_name" placeholder="project_name"
@if($param->project_name != null)
    value="{{$param->project_name}}"
@else
    value="{!!null!!}"
@endif
>
```

**projectcontroller**

```
$relevantKeys = $param = [
        'project_name' => null,
        'requester' => null,
        'user_name' => null,
        'status' => null,
        'requester_tell' => null,
        'division' => null,
    ];
foreach ($relevantKeys as $value) {
        if (!empty($request->{$value})) {
            $query = $query->where($value, 'like', '%' . $request->{$value} . '%');
            $param = $request->{$value};
            $a = 1;
        }
    }
    if ($a === 0) {
        $view = Project::where('status', '!=', 'completed')->get();
        return view('project.index', compact('view', 'cats', 'users', 'param'));
    }
    $view = $query->get();
    return view('project.index', compact('view', 'cats', 'users', 'param'));
}
```

I'm getting this error

Trying to get property 'project_name' of non-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with **!empty** or you don't need to call else part. if **'If'** part not execute then it'll auto null.

```
<input type="search" name="project_name" placeholder="project_name" value="@if(!empty($param->project_name)) {{$param->project_name}} @endif">
```

Or you can use ternary operator as well

```
<input type="search" name="project_name" placeholder="project_name" value="{{ ($param->project_name) ? $param->project_name : '' }}">
```

**Or**

```
<input type="search" name="project_name" placeholder="project_name" value="{{  $param['project_name'] ?? '' }}">
```

Comment: I didn't see any of them

Comment: value = "{{$ param ['project_name'] ?? ''}}"
Then it worked

Comment: Great! You are getting array that's why and you called as it object.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of you are sending

> $param->project_name as null

Try sending some other data in that variable like "-" or ignore that variable to proceed .